Node-Gyp MSVS version issues *only* when building with includes
On windows, I have a top-level node-gyp binding.gyp and a single component binding.gyp, with more to come.
Top-level binding.gyp:
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "all",
      "type": "none",
      "dependencies": [
        "my_component/binding.gyp:component"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "includes": [
    "my_component/binding.gyp"
  ]
}

my_component\binding.gyp:
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "component",
      "type": "shared_library",
      "sources": [
        "my_component.cpp"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
      ],
      "dependencies": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
      ],
      "libraries": [
        "-lwtsapi32.lib",
        "-luserenv.lib"
      ],
      "defines": [
        "NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS"
      ],
      "configurations": {
        "Release": {
          "msvs_configuration_platform": "x64"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

At the moment I'm using msvs 2019, with an appropriate windows sdk configured.
Here's the issue -
Running node-gyp clean configure build in just my component directory completes fine.
If I step upward and run node-gyp clean configure build in my top-level directory, I suddenly get confusing version errors:
PS C:\mypath> node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@10.2.0
gyp info using node@20.16.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args 'build\\binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
  nothing.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  nothing.vcxproj -> C:\mypath\build\Release\\nothing.lib
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(439,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2
015 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2015 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the cu
rrent Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\mypath\build\my_component\component.vcxproj]

And, indeed, inspecting the generated build\my_component\component.vcxproj when building from the top level does show it trying to use a platform toolset of 140 instead of the intended 142 exhibited in the component-only build, my_component\build\component.vcxproj.
As shown my top-level binding doesn't touch msvs settings whatsoever, and this is occuring within the same terminal so all the environment variables are the same.  Why might I be seeing this botched version behaviour when building from the top level but not when building my component directly?
node -v v20.16.0,
node-gyp -v v10.2.0
